# Understanding subsets of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

You can see here ([Find all possible subset combos in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752002/find-all-possible-subset-combos-in-an-array)) , that one solution presented is

```
var sets = (function(input, size){
    var results = [], result, mask, i, total = Math.pow(2, input.length);
    for(mask = size; mask < total; mask++){
        result = [];
        i = input.length - 1; 
        do{
            if( (mask & (1 << i)) !== 0){
            result.push(input[i]);
        }
        }while(i--);
        if( result.length >= size){
        results.push(result);
        }
    }   

return results; 
})(['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 2);
console.log(sets);
```

Firstly I would like to know exactly what size, and mask are doing. I.e why do we need a second param for our function. Also I did soe research on bitwise operators but am still not sure what and why we are doing

```
mask & (1 << i)) !== 0
```

What is this implying?

Comment: Why haven't you asked this in the referred question, say as a comment to the answer?

Comment: Its from 2013, and due to large text I will have to write to understand, a new question is much more appropriate.

Comment: `mask & (1 << i)` checks if the i-the bit of mask (interpreted as a signed 32-bit integer) is set to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *size* parameter is needed because the original question was to produce subsets of a minimal size (of 2). The parameter allows you to specify that minimal size. This is nice, because you can then use the same code to get all subsets with a minimal size of 3.

The variable *mask* takes all integer values that can be made with *input.length* bits. So, represented in binary, *mask* takes these values:

```
000000
000001
000010
000011
000100
... etc...
111100
111101
111110
111111
```

Every 1 bit signals that the corresponding element from the input array should be part of the subset. So the above values of *mask* represent the following subsets:

```
[]
['a']
['b']
['a','b']
['c']
... etc ...
['c','d','e','f']
['a','c','d','e','f']
['b','c','d','e','f']
['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

It is a bit confusing because we write binary representations with the least-significant bit on the right, while arrays are shown with the 0<sup>th</sup> element on the left.

From those sub arrays, only those with minimal *size* elements are retained in the results. So in the case of *size* = 2, the first 3 are not retained: the first one that stays is `['a','b']`.

For that reason the algorithm was a bit improved, and *mask* does not start from 0, because it already is sure not to find a large enough subset with *mask* smaller or equal to *size*. So that is why the `for` loop starts with that value. But it is not that important. It would also work starting with zero:

```
for (mask = 0; mask < total; mask++)
```

Then concerning the `if`: it tests whether a certain bit is set in the binary representation of *mask*: for that a single bit (1) is shifted to the left (so it becomes something like 10000 in binary representation) and then it is **AND**-ed (with `&`) with *mask*. For instance, if *mask* is at a certain moment 101001 and the shifted bit is 10000 then this `&` operation works like this:

```
mask: 101001
bit:   10000
------------
AND:  000000
```

Another example:

```
mask: 101001
bit:    1000
------------
AND:  001000
```

So, the `if` condition tests whether the bit at position *i* in *mask* (starting at the right of the binary representation) is set or not. If it is set, the value `mask & (1 << i))` will be equal to `(1 << i)` (like for instance 1000), if it is not set this expression evaluates to 0. So by doing the `!== 0` test you effectively test that the bit is set. Only in that case the corresponding element from the input array is added to the subset.

#### Example run

Let's say we call the function with these arguments:

```
(['a','b','c'], 2);
```

Then *total* = 8, and *mask* runs from 2 to 7. Put in binary terms, *mask* takes the following binary values:

```
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Note that every bit ("column") in the above table corresponds to an element of the array, and its value (0 or 1) decides whether that element should be in the sub array.

Other values of *mask* are not interesting: smaller values (like binary 001 or 000) represent sub-arrays that have too few elements -- we need at least two. Higher values (like 1000, 1001, ...) have too many bits: the left-most bit does not correspond to any element in the input array, since we only have 3 elements in the array. So that means we have all the interesting values for *mask* in the above table.

The next thing that happens in the code, is finding the 1-bits in a particular value of *mask*. We use the variable *i* to denote the 0-based number of the bit (its position starting from the right of the binary representation). This *i* will start at 2 and decrease until 0 (so 2, 1, and 0: each pointing to one of the three bits in *mask*):

```
i = input.length - 1; 
do { ... } while (i--);
```

For a given bit-number *i*, the bit's value in *mask* is extracted with:

```
mask & (1 << i)
```

So let's do all of the above with *mask* = 2 (i.e. 010 in binary). These are the values that are calculated:

```
result = []
i = 2
(1 << i) == 4 // 100 in binary: a 1-bit shifted twice to the left
mask & (1 << i) == 0 // because mask does not have that bit set
```

The next iteration for *i*:

```
i = 1
(1 << i) == 2 // 010 in binary: a 1-bit shifted once to the left
mask & (1 << i) == 2 // because mask has that bit set 
result = ['b'] // because 'b' is the value at index i.
```

The last iteration for *i*:

```
i = 0
(1 << i) == 1 // 001 in binary: a 1-bit not shifted at all
mask & (1 << i) == 0 // because mask does not have that bit set
```

Now, the length of *result* is checked, but for this particular value of *mask* it is too small:

```
result.length == 1 // see above, so nothing is added to the *results* (with 's')
```

All has been done for *mask* == 2, so now the above is repeated for *mask* == 3 (binary 011):

```
result = []
i = 2
(1 << i) == 4 // 100 in binary: a 1-bit shifted twice to the left
mask & (1 << i) == 0 // because mask does not have that bit set
```

The next iteration for *i*:

```
i = 1
(1 << i) == 2 // 010 in binary: a 1-bit shifted once to the left
mask & (1 << i) == 2 // because mask has that bit set 
result = ['b'] // because 'b' is the value at index i.
```

The last iteration for *i* (different result here):

```
i = 0
(1 << i) == 1 // 001 in binary: a 1-bit not shifted at all
mask & (1 << i) == 1 // because mask has that bit set as well (different!)
result = ['b','a'] // because 'a' is the value at index i.
```

Now, the length of *result* is checked again, and this time it is big enough:

```
result.length == 2 // see above
results = [['b','a']]
```

...etc.

Note that *results* (plural) is an array of arrays, so eventually it will grow to:

```
results = [['b','a'], ['c','a'], ['c','b'], ['c','b','a']]
```

The sub arrays have their elements in reversed order because the loop of *i* iterates backward. The sub arrays would be ordered normally if *i* would increment from 0 onwards (which is possible without any issue).

#### Limitations

Because bit operations like `<<` and `&` require their arguments to be 32 bit integers, the code at hand will only work for input arrays that have at the most 32 elements.

Comment: Is there a reason total = 2^(input.length), im guessing this is due to binary as well

Comment: Perhaps you could run me through a test case. Say we call (['a','b','c'],2). Now total = 2^(3). So total is 8. Now mask = 2, so we keep looping until mask is 8. i becomes 7... er now what after reading your answer im still a tad bit confused

Comment: I extended my answer. I hope this is detailed enough to get the grips on it.

Comment: Thanks, could you expand on more on mask & (1 << i).  Are these kind of like logic gates? I remember taking a class last semester like that.  It says "a<<b shifts in a binary representatin b to the left,shifting in zeroes from the right. " What does that mean here?

Comment: `1<<5` is the number 1 (binary 000000000001) shifted 5 times to the left, adding zeroes to the right: binary 000000100000. As you see, 5 zeroes were added to the right. This is equal to *2^5*. With *i*: `1<<i` is *2^i*.

Comment: ahh, and the and sign is doing..?

Comment: It performs a logical AND on each bit position. I explained that with two examples in my answer. The purpose in this algorithm is to extract a particular bit from *mask* and forget about all other bits.

Comment: What does it mean  "because mask has that bit set "

Comment: It means that in the binary representation of the *mask* value, the bit -- at the position given by *i* -- is 1.

Comment: I have given several examples in my answer. Try to solve this: what is the result of `01010 & 01000` (binary)?

Comment: & means multiply no? so 10 * 8 = 80 -> 1010000

Comment: It is not multiplication. As I wrote in my answer it is the **AND** operation. It is a [bit-wise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Comment: Oh we learned in school that an AND operation is like A times B. I just remember the truth table and how anything anded with 0 is 0.ok I'll check it out once I'm home

Comment: You can take it as multiplication, but then you must perform the multiplication bit-by-bit: so for `0101 & 0100` it would be 0*0, 1*1, 0*0, 1*0, resulting in `0100`.

Comment: A programmer's mind gets moulded into this binary bit thinking after some time :)

Comment: The reason we are thinking of bits in this questions is because we started using &, and << right?

Comment: Not really, it starts when you hear the question *"find subsets"*. That is a binary operation. Imagine you have a bag full of toys, and you are asked to create a subset of it in another (empty) bag: you will take each toy out the first bag and decide (yes or no: binary!) whether to put it in the other bag. Since these are binary choices, die-hard programmers immediately think of using binary representations and bit operations like `&` and `<<`.

Comment: Would you mind telling me what >-1 does, in the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring

Comment: That is something completely different. Check the manual on [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf): *"...returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present."*. So `>-1` is a way to check if the element was found.

Comment: Why not just !=-1?

Comment: Because it is one character less? But why bother about that? There is seldom only one way to do things.

Comment: I have a new question related to bit operators, perhaps you could help me out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516811/matching-names-with-corresponding-32-bit-unsigned-integers/38516930?noredirect=1#comment64432019_38516930

Comment: Apologies they just started responding after I asked you

Comment: I got the answer for that problem! Do you think my solution is super inefficient? Just wondering because it looks a bit ugly

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I don't think I will get any more responses on this question I posted and was wondering if you could chip in your two cents  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542069/find-separation-values-from-a-starting-node

Comment: Do you have time later today to talk about this subset question? I tried coding it on my own today and I got stuck on one specific part, that I think would be better to talk about in chat

Comment: Sure, remind me what was the subset question? Oh wait, you mean *this* question here. Ready for chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118131/discussion-between-cresjoy-and-trincot

Comment: I likely wont be home for another 2 hours, Ill let you know

Comment: Actually I'm not busy now I have a break ill be in chat

Comment: Hi, do you have time now?

Comment: Ahh Apologies, I just saw this now. I'll catch you later i guess!

Comment: Hi trincot, I'm free for most of the day today, just let me know when. Thanks

Comment: Hi, got time today?

Comment: Hi Trincot, could you give me your thoughts on this question when you are free.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637882/finding-order-between-many-events. The given solution does not work for many of the test cases, and is a bit hard to understand

Comment: Hi, did you miss my comment, or are you busy? Take your time ,but just wondering

Comment: Hey trincot , do you have some free time later? I wanted to discuss this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414700/amazon-water-collected-between-towers

Comment: No worries, I have to go out and do some stuff now for probably three hours just message me whenever. :)

Comment: If your not on then, Ill bug you when you wake up dont worry :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121978/discussion-between-muntasir-alam-and-trincot).

Comment: Hi, I have really quick quick question when you have a minute or two :)

Comment: Ok im in chat  now

Comment: Hey trincot, got some time? I wanted to ask about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360926/python-match-the-struct-of-a-list

Comment: Seems the old chat is frozen, how do I make a new one?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122904/muntasir, I made this chat not sure if you can join it though

Comment: Hi, I'm back in chat

Comment: Couldn't make it. I am available now for 2 hours or so.

Comment: Here again in chat

Comment: Looks like our timezone is really messing things up haha. Do you have like a MSN or email-chat type thing your usually on?

Comment: I do have some of these, but am not connecting to these during office hours. I am trying to keep an eye on StackOverflow though, even when at the office, but it is no guarantee I can reply quickly. I am in timezone GMT+1 (currently GMT+2 because of daylight saving).

Comment: Ok just woke up and am in chat

Comment: Going to be home in an hour and on for 3 hrs ish till I fall asleep xd

Comment: That was my night :-) I'm up again.

Comment: Hi there, got time today?

Comment: Great, i'm in chat

Comment: Sorry, I had unexpected visitors. Maybe now?

Comment: Hey wondered if you had some time, whenever you are awake? Had a question about this answer specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/14944957/6757245

Comment: I have time in the coming hours. Let me know when you are awake :-)