# Finding order between many events

Tags: javascript

Currently solving a puzzle and looking for some tips on sorting by events ordered. I would like to know what exactly is the procedure I should be following. Consider this

I input a number, then there `n` inputs
    each input has two events, where of for `event1 event2`, and `event1` happens before `event2`.

Consider the input

```
6
Eatfood Cuthair
Eatfood BrushTeeth
School  EatFood
School  DoHair
DoHair   Meeting
Meeting Brushteeth
```

The output will be

```
school -> dohair-> eatfood -> meeting -> cuthair -> brushteeth
```

In that order. Since if we write everything down, school is indeed the first thing that occurs, and then dohair is second.  If more than one possible ordering exists simply output one. You may assume that all events are connected in some way, and no circular dependencies exist.

What I am thinking about doing is making two arrays, one which has all `eventOne's` and all `eventTwo's`. I'm not really sure where to go from here though. I would like to do this in javascript. Thanks! Any hints or algorithms are suggested

Another Input

```
6
vote_140_prof announce_140_prof
vote_140_prof first_day_of_classes
dev_shed_algo vote_140_prof
dev_shed_algo do_hair
do_hair big_meeting
big_meeting first_day_of_classes
```

Output

```
dev_shed_algo do_hair vote_140_prof big_meeting announce_140_prof first_day_of_classes
```

I found the solution file on my computer, its in python which I don't know, but hopefully this will help others understand the problem

```
from collections import defaultdict

def toposort(graph, roots):
    res = [i for i in roots]
    queue = [i for i in roots]
    while queue:
        for i in graph[queue.pop(0)]:
            if i not in res:
                res.append(i)
                queue.append(i)
    return res

graph = defaultdict(set)
a_set = set()
b_set = set()

for i in range(int(input())):
    a, b = input().split()
    a_set.add(a)
    b_set.add(b)
    graph[a].add(b)

print(" ".join(i for i in toposort(graph, a_set - b_set)))
```

**My attempt**

```
var words =
    'vote_140_prof announce_140_prof vote_140_prof first_day_of_classes devshed_algo vote_140_prof dev_shed_algo do_hair do_hair big_meeting big_meeting first_day_of_classes';

var events = words;

events = events.split(/\s+/);
console.log(events);

var obj = {};
for (var i = 0 ; i < events.length ; i++)
    {
        var name = events[i];
        if(obj[name] === undefined )
            {
                obj[name] = [];
            }

        obj[name].push(events[i%2 === 1 ? i-1 : i+1]);
    }
console.log(obj);
```

**FORMATING**

```
function sequenceEvents(pairs){
        var edges = pairs.reduce(function(edges,pair){
            edges.set(pair[0],[]).set(pair[1],[]);
            new Map();
        });

        pairs.forEach(function(edges,pair){

            edges.set(pair[0],[]).set(pair[1],[]);

        });

        var result = [];

        while(edges.size){
            var children = new Set([].concat.apply([],[...edges.value()]));
            var roots = [...edges.keys()].filter(function(event){
                !children.has(event);
            });

            if(!roots.length) throw "Cycle detected";
        roots.forEach(function(root){
           result.push(root);
           edges.delete(root);

        });

        }

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: So you input a number that references one of the events from the first list and it needs to output that event from the first list followed by that event from the second list?

Comment: I forgot to add If more than one possible ordering exists simply output one. I guess the question is a bit odd to understand I'm not really sure what you mean. Basically the idea is to just find the first event that occurs. Even if something is event one for one input, it can be event 2 for another input, in that case that input 2's input1 is the first thing that occured and so on

Comment: Could potentially be quite complex code, as you'll need to check for circular references, orphans, etc. [What have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Oh yes "You may assume that all events are connected in some way, and no circular dependencies exist. ", I will add that in. apologies

Comment: @cresjoy I am confused as to what the input is?

Comment: In your example above, there's no rule that declares which order Meeting and CutHair are in. They could be swapped and it would still be valid. You require uniqueness of answer, or it's going to get messy. At the moment, the inputs are insufficient to give a single solution. Same applies to your second input supplied.

Comment: I wish I had the original link, for some reason its dead, I remember I have one of the test cases though I'll add it in the answer

Comment: @SinanGuclu. We type in n amount of inputs of the form event1 event2. We do this n amount of times. So there are n event1's and n event2's. The objective is to find which event1 is the FIRST event. I added another test case

Comment: @ManoDestra, I am not asking for the answer, but am rather confused on where to start. Any hints or algorithms which can get me started would be nice, after that I will gladly post my code

Comment: @cresjoy Firstly, you need to supply the code that you've tried so far. Secondly, you need to ensure uniqueness of solution based on the inputs, otherwise your algorithm will have to produce multiple solutions. You could use a brute force approach and take the unique tasks, then go through every possible permutation of those events, and check each for validity against the input rules. If all rules are satisfied, then add that permutation to your list of possible solutions.

Comment: To find the first event you could use an algorithm where you put the input into an array of pairs of: (before, after). Then you pretend that the first item in that array is actually the first thing that must happen. Then you look at every other item in the array, and if it's after value equals your current before value, you update your current pair to be the new one.

Comment: Extension to my previous comment: You can disqualify a few permutations immediately though as some tasks are never on the left hand side, therefore will never be in the first index position of any solution. Same applies to any on the left hand side that do not appear on the right.

Comment: @Davis, thank you I will try that right now

Comment: Added a python solution which I found in the question folder on my computer, currently going to attempt at solving this and update you guys

Comment: Grr, this is tricky. I posted what I think is a good start. Basically I made an object with arrays inside with events corresponding to each events. Now I need to find out how to filter them

Comment: @Davis, Could you provide more pseudo code? I like that approach but I think I need more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python algorithm is not correct. It will fail for this input:

```
3
A B
A C
C B
```

It will output:

```
A, B, C
```

...which conflicts with the last rule. This is because it wrongly assumes that the children of any root-event can be safely added to the result, and depend on no other events. In the above case, it will identify A as root, and B and C as its children. Then it will pop of C from that list, and add it to the result, without seeing that C depends on B, which is not in the result yet.

As others have noted, you need to make sure the capitalisation is consistent. `Brushteeth` and `BrushTeeth` are considered different events. The same is true for `EatFood` and `Eatfood`.

I provide here a solution. I hope the inline comments explain well enough what is happening:

```js
function sequenceEvents(pairs) {
    // Create a Map with a key for each(!) event, 
    // and add an empty array as value for each of them.
    var edges = pairs.reduce(
        // Set both the left and right event in the Map 
        //   (duplicates get overwritten)
        (edges, pair) => edges.set(pair[0], []).set(pair[1], []),
        new Map() // Start with an empty Map
    );
    // Then add the children (dependent events) to those arrays:
    pairs.forEach( pair => edges.get(pair[0]).push(pair[1]) );

    var result = [];
    // While there are still edges...
    while (edges.size) {
        // Get the end points of the edges into a Set
        var children = new Set( [].concat.apply([], [...edges.values()]) );
        // Identify the parents, which are not children, as roots
        var roots = [...edges.keys()].filter( event => !children.has(event) );
        // As we still have edges, we must find at least one root among them.
        if (!roots.length) throw "Cycle detected";
        roots.forEach(root => {
            // Add the new roots to the result, all events they depend on
            // are already in the result:
            result.push(root);
            // Delete the edges that start with these events, since the
            // dependency they express has been fulfilled:
            edges.delete(root);
        });
    }
    return result;
}


// I/O
var input = document.querySelector('#input');
var go = document.querySelector('#go');
var output = document.querySelector('#output');

go.onclick = function() {
    // Get lines from input, ignoring the initial number
    // ... then split those lines in pairs, resulting in
    // an array of pairs of events
    var pairs = input.value.trim().split(/\n/).slice(1)
                     .map(line => line.split(/\s+/));
    var sequence = sequenceEvents(pairs);
    output.textContent = sequence.join(', ');
}
```

```html
Input:<br>
<textarea id="input" rows=7>6
EatFood CutHair
EatFood BrushTeeth
School  EatFood
School  DoHair
DoHair   Meeting
Meeting BrushTeeth
</textarea>
<button id="go">Sequence Events</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

#### Without arrow functions nor `apply`

As in comments you indicated you like to have the code without arrow functions first:

```
function sequenceEvents(pairs) {
    // Create a Map with a key for each(!) event, 
    // and add an empty array as value for each of them.
    var edges = pairs.reduce(function (edges, pair) {
        // Set both the left and right event in the Map 
        //   (duplicates get overwritten)
        return edges.set(pair[0], []).set(pair[1], []);
    }, new Map() ); // Start with an empty Map
    // Then add the children (dependent events) to those arrays:
    pairs.forEach(function (pair) {
        edges.get(pair[0]).push(pair[1]);
    });

    var result = [];
    // While there are still edges...
    while (edges.size) {
        // Get the end points of the edges into a Set
        var children = new Set(
            [...edges.values()].reduce(function (children, value) {
                return children.concat(value);
            }, [] )
        );
        // Identify the parents, which are not children, as roots
        var roots = [...edges.keys()].filter(function (event) {
            return !children.has(event);
        });
        if (!roots.length) throw "Cycle detected";
        roots.forEach(function (root) {
            // Add the new roots to the result, all events they depend on
            // are already in the result:
            result.push(root);
            // Delete the edges that start with these events, since the
            // dependency they express has been fulfilled:
            edges.delete(root);
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: By the way have you tried the other test case I put in the question, Either that test case is wrong ( I just pasted it off the website), or perhaps I didnt type it in properly? I'm talking about the test case of dev_shed_algo... from my question

Comment: Also, I tried formatting this to  syntax that I am a bit more familiar with, I added my attempt at the top, but it looks like once again the darn => is confusing me,even though I thought I got it after you explaining it like a million times haha. I edited it above, what I wrote clearly is wrong, but I don't really know how to translate it. What I usually like to do is take the simpler syntax version, and then rewrite it in your more "complex" syntax

Comment: The other test case is in fact exactly the same problem -- it just uses different words. Replace every `vote_140_prof` by `EatFood`, every `announce_140_prof` by `CutHair`... etc, and you have the first problem there! Now, this kind of puzzles often has more than one correct answer, so you cannot really say that if two programs produce a different solution, that one of them must be wrong. They can both be right.

Comment: Concerning the translation you did  for the `=>` syntax: the `filter` and `reduce` callback functions need a `return` statement. In the `=>` syntax that is implied if you use no braces. With the `reduce` at the start you also made another little mistake: the `new Map()` part should not occur within the function block; it is a second argument (after the function) of `reduce`.

Comment: Added a section to my answer with the arrow-less code.

Comment: Was out all weekend for a trip, just started reading this. Thanks, I'm taking a look right now. Where do I find info on the method .set? I was just reading on Sets from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set, dont see anything on .set though

Comment: I am on a trip right now, so can't comment much. The `edges` variable is not a Set, but a Map, as you can see in the second argument passed to `reduce`: `new Map()` and the comments I had added to the code. This is the value of `edges` at the first "iteration". Then it just gets extended with key/value pairs via the [`.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) calls.

Comment: Could you let me know when you are back from your trip? I want to confirm some things in chat. No rush. Thanks

Comment: I have a bit of time now (still on holiday).

Comment: awkward. Just saw this. I have to do some stuff for work now, about the same time you messaged me I'll be free most of tommorow. Just let me know whenever, no worries.

Comment: Free for the next couple hours.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Here's my shot at the problem.

```
var makePair = function(i0, i1) {
    return {start: i0, end: i1};
};

var mp = makePair;

var makeBefores = function(pairs) {
    var befores = {};
  pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
    if (befores[pair.end] == null) {
        befores[pair.end] = [pair.start];
    } else {
        befores[pair.end].push(pair.start);
    }
    if (befores[pair.start] == null) {
        befores[pair.start] = [];
    }
  });
  for (var key in befores) {
    console.log("after " + key + "there is:");
    for (var i = 0; i < befores[key].length; i++) {
        console.log(befores[key][i]);
    }
  }

  return befores;
};

var shouldGoBefore = function(item, before) {
    for (var i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
    if (item == before[i]) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

var sortEvents = function(pairs) {
    if (pairs.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  if (pairs.length === 1) {
    return [pairs[0].start, pairs[0].end];
  }
  console.log(pairs);
  var befores = makeBefores(pairs);
  var sorted = [];
  for (var key in befores) {
    var added = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    console.log('checking if ' + sorted[i] + ' should go before ' + befores[key]);
        if (shouldGoBefore(sorted[i], befores[key])) {
            //console.log("splicing");
        sorted.splice(i, 0, key);
        added = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!added) {
        sorted.push(key);
    }
  }
  return sorted.reverse();
}

var pairs = [mp('vote_140_prof','announce_140_prof'),mp('vote_140_prof','first_day_of_classes'),mp('dev_shed_algo','vote_140_prof'),mp('dev_shed_algo','do_hair'),mp('do_hair','big_meeting'),mp('big_meeting','first_day_of_classes'),mp('announce_140_prof','first_day_of_classes')];
console.log(sortEvents(pairs));
```

One reason things may not have been working is your test data had inconsistent capitalization. The results of this run are:

```
Array [ "School", "EatFood", "CutHair", "Meeting", "BrushTeeth", "DoHair" ]
```

I'm going to test it on your other data set but I believe this fulfills the prompt. I'm going to write up how it works in a minute.

Note that this doesn't do any file IO or reading of lines. It takes the input to `sortEvents` as an array of objects that have a `start` and `end` property, which I provided a helper method `makePair` to create.

The solution works by building a dictionary of what elements go before which others.

If you had an input like:

```
a->b
c->a
c->b
b->d
```

The dictionary would be like this:

```
a->[c],
c->[],
b->[a,c],
d->[b]
```

Then we use an array as a sort of linked list and we go through it seeing whether we have to insert something. So for example, if we are trying to see where `a` should be inserted and the list is `c`, then we would look at the dictionary for `c`, see that `c` is in it and then we know that before `a` there is supposed to be `c`, therefore we have to insert `a` after `c`

Comment: I don;t think this is ordering properly, DoHair should be second, your code is saying EatFood is second, also I tried the other test case and the order is mixed up. I'm going to look at your solution closely, perhaps you missed something small?

Comment: I found the link for the test cases here http://potw.quinnftw.com/problem/2015/6/

Comment: There isn't a single right answer. Many different answers could satisfy the constraints. This algorithm provides one right answer. The only specification for DoHair is that it is before Meeting -> which it is.

Comment: Actually, I realized what my mistake was, brushteeth was capitalized in two different ways too which means that it was getting placed oddly.

Comment: DoHair is before meeting, meeting is before brushteeth, eatfood is before brushteeth, and cuthair, but school is before eatfood

Comment: But the specification says `School  EatFood` which means School is before EatFood, right?

Comment: Ah yes your right.. I made that test case up on my own, looks like I got confused. I'm going to try it with the data on the actual question website I posted. To see if it works

Comment: Great. I hope that it works out. I found that I kept capitalizing things wrong so if it doesn't work, make sure you aren't trying to compare `Brushteeth` with `BrushTeeth`

Comment: I think I'm capitilizing things wrong. Would you mind testing the cases from the webpage I posted and see how things go?

Comment: You've been right @cresjoy, my code was malfunctioning in some cases. The code is fixed now. I'm going to fix the explanation too.

Comment: I'm going to take at this code later tonight. Currently working on some PHP stuff for work :(, thanks I'll probably have some more questions I'll let you know.

Comment: It looks like vote_140 and big meeting are switched though according to the output

Comment: I think this time it actually satisfies all the constraints. If it's not working I'm going to have to think about this algorithm again later.

Comment: I'll take a look at it tonight. Not sure why one of them is switched either. Thanks for your help :). Talk to you soon

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your dictionary? What I was thinking was to make a counter that keeps adding one before a specific element

Comment: I don' get how the part after "the dictionary looks like this"

Answer (score -1):

Take a hash map start with first event and put it's value to 0 than whenever you encounter event 2 check the value of event 1 in hash than put a smaller value for event 2. Once complete sort hash by value.

Bingo

```
line = input();
myMap = dict()
i=0
while i < line:
        event1 = raw_input()
        event2 = raw_input()
        if event1 in myMap :
                myMap[event2] = myMap[event1]+1
        elif event2 in myMap:
                myMap[event1] = myMap[event2]-1
        else :
                myMap[event1] = 0
                myMap[event2] = 1
        i=i+1
        print i
        print myMap
```

I don't know why some people downvoted but yes it's working, Atleast on both your samples

Sample input and output

```
6
eatfood
cuthair
1
{'eatfood': 0, 'cuthair': 1}
eatfood
brushteeth
2
{'brushteeth': 1, 'eatfood': 0, 'cuthair': 1}
school
eatfood
3
{'brushteeth': 1, 'eatfood': 0, 'school': -1, 'cuthair': 1}
school
dohair
4
{'brushteeth': 1, 'eatfood': 0, 'school': -1, 'cuthair': 1, 'dohair': 0}
dohair
meeting
5
{'school': -1, 'brushteeth': 1, 'cuthair': 1, 'dohair': 0, 'eatfood': 0, 'meeting': 1}
meeting
brushteeth
6
{'school': -1, 'brushteeth': 2, 'cuthair': 1, 'dohair': 0, 'eatfood': 0, 'meeting': 1}
```

The code is in python, feel free to convert in javascript

Comment: Please supply event1 and event2 in separate lines instead of separated by spaces

Comment: It looks pretty good, any idea on how to in javascript? I can't really follow your procedure