# Matching the structure of a list?

Tags: python, list

For example:

```
A=[1,[2,3],[4,[5,6]],7]
B=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

How can I get `[2,[3,4],[5,[6,7]],8]`?

Comment: Please provide more information about the desired transformation from input to output. How does the output in your example relate to the input?

Comment: @CraigBurgler I'm guessing the OP means to copy the same sublists as the other, so keeping the same 'struct'(ure) of the lists

Comment: return [2,[3,4],[5,[6,7]],8]

Comment: Although he didn't post any of his thoughts or how he wants to do this, I must admit this is an interesting question

Comment: My Thoughts would be to check whenever `isinstance(A[i],list)` occurs, and keep a starting index and ending index. Then try to formulate an array like that in array `B`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a pretty simple recursive function:

```
def match(struct, source):
    try:
        return [match(i, source) for i in struct]
    except TypeError:
        return next(source)

A=[1,[2,3],[4,[5,6]],7]
B=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
match(A, iter(B))
# [2, [3, 4], [5, [6, 7]], 8]
```

Here is a version of the function that might be a little easier for some people to understand:

```
def match(struct, source, index=0):
    if isinstance(struct, list):
        r = []
        for item in struct:
            next, index = match(item, source, index)
            r.append(next)
        return r, index
    else:
        return source[index], index + 1

A=[1,[2,3],[4,[5,6]],7]
B=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
match(A, B)
```

The basic idea is to loop over the input structure depth first, and consume values from source accordingly. When we hit a number, we can simply take one number from source. If we hit a list we need to apply this algorithm to that list. Along the way need to keep track of how many items we've consumed.

The first version of the algorithm does all this, but in a slightly different way. `iter(B)` creates an iterator that tracks how many items from b have been consumed and provided the next item when i call `next(source)` so I don't have to track index explicitly. The try/except checks to see if I can loop over `struct`. If I can, a list is returned, if I cannot the expect block gets executed and `next(source)` is returned.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the exact algorithm for someone who isn't familiar at all with python? Interested on how you thought of it, unfortunately I don't program in python though.

Comment: @Bi Rico: Hrmph. I was writing basically the same function, but checking the type of the current entry to decide when to bottom out. Yours is shorter and yet less moral. You really want to detect the bottom of the recursion by trying to recurse one level more and catching an exception? This is philosophy, I suppose!

Comment: catching an exception (duck typing) is much more Pythonic than explicit type-checking